IDE adding unit to uses clause, ignoring compiler directive
This is the start of the interface section of one data module of program PrgServer.
This has a conditional define PRGSERVER in Project options, Delphi compiler, conditional defines
uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
   DateUtils, Db, DBClient, Provider, Variants, System.Math, VCL.Imaging.Jpeg,
   INIFiles, x_lib, SQLScripts, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
   FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
   FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
   FireDAC.DAPT, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
   FireDAC.Phys.MSSQLDef, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf,
   FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL,
   FireDAC.Phys.IB, FireDAC.Phys.IBDef, FireDAC.Stan.Consts,
   {$IF defined(PRGADMIN) or defined(PRGSERVER)}
   DMDataBaseAdmin, MyAdminDM,
   {$ifend}
   MyDM, FrmBusy;

type
  TDataModuleData = class(TAdminDataModule)

Another program PrgAdmin also uses this unit and has conditional define PRGADMIN.
The TAdminDataModule type is defined in MyAdminDM
If I save this file or start a compile/build, the IDE (autosaves and) changes the Uses clause to
uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
   DateUtils, Db, DBClient, Provider, Variants, System.Math, VCL.Imaging.Jpeg,
   INIFiles, x_lib, SQLScripts, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
   FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
   FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
   FireDAC.DAPT, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
   FireDAC.Phys.MSSQLDef, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf,
   FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL,
   FireDAC.Phys.IB, FireDAC.Phys.IBDef, FireDAC.Stan.Consts,
   {$IF defined(PRGADMIN) or defined(PRGSERVER)}
   DMDataBaseAdmin, MyAdminDM,
   {$ifend}
   MyDM, FrmBezig, Provider, MyAdminDM;  // <<==

and this gives a compile error E2004 Identifier redeclared for the MyAdminDM.
I expect the conditional defines to ensure that the correct units are used, and not that the unit is added again because of the Type TDataModuleData = class(TAdminDataModule).
Can I prevent this somehow?
Saving the file without the added AdminDM does not help, it gets added if the file is open in the IDE.
Notes:

This is just 'a' unit (data module), not the project file
All units are added to the PrgServer project
This is a 64 bit Windows program in Delphi 12.1
This change to the unit is also made if I save the file manually, if I edit it in an external editor, or if I close with Save Changes? -> No (In that case I see it getting added just before the window closes)
The change to the unit is also made even if it is not open in the IDE (i.e. when compiling)
Note that the 'Provider' unit is also added (there are design time TDataSetProviders), but I don't get an error for that
MyadminDM is found in the Search Path
Maybe related: Stop the IDE from adding uses units automatically, and from there: Why is my Component auto adding other units to the uses interface?, or to make things more complicated: Add unit to project is removing a compiler directive from the project source


Does MyadminDM declares any components inside. Based on my experience IDE is automatically adding only units that are required by components that have been placed on the form. If not then the latest Delphi might also be automatically adding needed units into uses clause based on classes used within. In such case you should make sure that all code that relies on MyadminDM is also wrapped in similar compiler directive.

This is a quite known bug and already around since many years

@SilverWarior That data mdoule has no design time components; it references component types in code: if (Components[i] is TDatasetProvider) then with TDatasetProvider(Components[i]) do Options := Options - [poUseQuoteChar];

@DelphiCoder Any references? Info over there might lead to a workaround

Unfortunately not, only my own experience (used to happend to me with XE2, e.g.) and maybe forum post somewhere

Perhaps you can find some hints here: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2016/11/06/conditional-uses-clause-considered-harmful/

Interface uses clauses and project requires clauses are managed by the IDE, and it doesn't like it when directives are present in them, so try to avoid that whenever possible. I know it is not always possible, so you just have to fix them manually when the IDE messes them up.

If you the conditional uses at the end of the list, it might not add them unnecessarily. I'm not promising anything here, it just has worked for me in the past.
